# Failed to start Raise network interfaces

Tags: ubuntu, network-programming, virtual-machine

I am setting a Ubuntu's VM (16.04.1 LTS) and I get an error when I try to connect from WinSCP in my windows to the VMs. The error is: developmentHost does not exist.

The network/interfaces file is this one:

[image]

If I execute a `ifconfig` command I get this info:

[image]

On the other side, the Virtualbox configuration for both network adapters are:

[image: Adapter 1]

In the above picture I included the port redirection, because I want to connect with the VM withou editing the windows hosts file.

[image: Adapter 2]

Furthermore I get this error about interfaces when I reboot.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I don't know how to fix the failure but i can show you a shortcut to deal with this problem temporarily...

1-use this command to find out which interfaces are available in your system.
 # ip link
example: lo , enp0s8

2-add following lines in /etc/network/interfaces

auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet dhcp

3-restart your VM.
and it's done.

Comment: Instead of restarting VM, for me just sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart worked.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 16.04 there perhaps is no ethX interface anymore. This version now comes with the so called `Predictable Network Interface Names`, where the name of the interfaces can be determined by: `which tries to find fixed slot topology information in certain firmware interfaces and uses them to assign fixed names to interfaces which incorporate their physical location on the mainboard.` (refer to: [freedesktop.org](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/)). Hence you have to find out the correct interface names by using the command `ip a` which prints something like:

`1: lo: ...
 2: ensXX: ...
 n: ...`

before you can configure your `/etc/network/interfaces`

See also: [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/q/824376/229026)

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned something about a VM, if the hardware address changes then you might have the same issue as if you changed physical hardware.

Get current identifier for the network card:

root@mybox:/home/root# ip -a

1: ...

2: enp0df: .... (Your identifier will be different)

Update this information in:
/etc/network/interfaces

# The primary network interface

auto enp0df

iface enp0df inet dhcp

Restart network services:

/etc/init.d/networking restart

Answer (score 0):

i think  you should change network advanced option.
if you set option modo promisco to Permitir todo(permit all), it will work fine.

Comment: That isn't what promiscuous mode is for.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question,at last I found that I closed my windows service

**VMware NAT Service** and **VMnetDHCP**

just run them